# Qt: is there a way to send a signal when a QProcess writes a line to stdout

Tags: qt, qt4

I've found similar questions but never the exact answer. I have Qt program that starts a QProcess and writes the output to a QTextEdit box, so far so good. But it only does so when the program has ended. if possible I'd like the programs stdout to be printed in real-ish time. In an ideal world there would be some sort of signal that QProcess emits when there is a line ready to read, if its not possible with QProcess is it possible at all? Also Ideally you could still use the rest of the program while the process is running.

Heres some of the code i have so far, very simple, it just emits the first line of the QProcess stdout to a QTextEdit

```
...
extProcess::extProcess(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
    extProcess::extProcess(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    proc = new QProcess(this); //initialize proc
    arguments << "-v";
    connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(logReady()));

}

void extProcess::startProcess()
{
    emit clearLog();
    emit outLog("--Process started--");
    proc->start("/Users/jonathan/Desktop/testgg");
}

void extProcess::logReady()
{
       emit outLog(proc->readLine());
}
...
```

This is al alternate version I tried, this will show the entire QProcess output but still 
    only shows it when the program finishes.

```
    ...
    extProcess::extProcess(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)

{
    proc = new QProcess(this); //initialize proc
    proc->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::SeparateChannels);
    arguments << "-v";
    connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(logReady()));

}


void extProcess::logReady()
{

       while(proc->bytesAvailable()){
               emit outLog(proc->readLine());
       }
}



void extProcess::startProcess()
{
    emit clearLog();
    emit outLog("--Process started--");
    proc->start("/Users/jonathan/Desktop/testgg");
}



void extProcess::killProcess()
{
    proc->terminate();
    emit clearLog();
    emit outLog("--Process Terminated--");
}
....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [readAllStandardOutput()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.4/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput) for this exact purpose and it works for me.

However I did note that it won't recieve any standard output until the process actually flushes its output buffer ("\n" may not automagically do this, at least not in my entirely platform specific Windows experience).

Depending on how the child process writes its output (either a C app or a C++ app), it needs to call `fflush(stdout);` or end lines with `std::endl;` respectively.

Comment: Hmmm, so am i at the mercy of the program which I am calling? I'm testing the program with a program i wrote to emit a line every second or so but eventually i will be triggering an external process that i have no control over, fingers crossed there is a way, j

Comment: I just added std::endl to my test process and it works, it would be great if there were another way

Comment: I think some stdout's flush at \n, maybe printf() does.

Comment: You can always hope that the app that you're calling flushes the buffers regularly :)

Comment: haha, well i try not to leave things to luck :), if there were a way to do this without Qt it would be extremely useful, if i knew how I'd think about writing some sort of library for that, maybe its time to do some research on the matter, j

Comment: Qt or no Qt, you can't get stdout from a process that hasn't flushed it's stdout buffers :)

Comment: well then I be extra careful to use std::endl from now on, and i will endeavor to spread the word long and far.

Comment: @jonathan topf: use `std::endl` *judiciously*, not always.  For example, writing a large text file can be much faster if you use `\n`, then flush at key points, rather than flushing at the end of every line.  Some standard out also; for instance, if you have a loop that is just outputting, wait until after the loop to flush.

Answer (score 3):

[readLine()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.4/qiodevice.html#readLine) probably waits till the first '\n' character is read.

[readAllStandardOutput](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.4/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput) on the other hand returns all data available from the standard output of the process.

So it seems to me that if you use readAllStandardOutput() you may get more performance.

You have to try though.

Comment: I tried readAllStandardOutput() and it does return everything just fine but it still waits until the QProcess ends to end to emit the signal, j

Answer (score 2):

> In an ideal world there would be some sort of signal that QProcess emits when there is a line ready to read

Is the `Qprocess` signal `readyReadStandardOutput()` not exactly what your asking for ?

You can connect to it then is your slot get the available data `bytesAvailable()` and look for the `'/n'` chars. Or simply `readLine()` while `canReadLine()`.

Do not forget to start your process and don't wait for it to finish. Plus set-up the `ProcessChannelMode` to `SeparateChannels`.

**EDIT**

I do have a class that read line of a `QProcess` like this :

```
bool extProcess::logReady()
{
    while( proc->canReadLine())
    {
        QByteArray line = proc->readLine();
        /*do some with the line like copying it's content to a QTextEdit*/
    }
}
```

And it work quite well. **I not sure about the `emit outLog()` signal !** Are you try to pass a `QByteArray` through a signal ? The data contained in the `QByteArray` must be save in a buffer and you should pass the pointer to this array to anyone connected to it ...

But again if you don't want to use extra memory and deal with the "is the data consumed ? ... ", do what you need to do with the data in your `logReady()` method.

Comment: I just edited the above program and added your suggestions but it still waits for the program to end to trigger the signal